# VMWare support contract renewal

Tags: vmware

I bought a Dell box three years ago. It uses VMWare VSphere Client (desktop app) and has a few virtual servers. In the past three years, there was no software update to the VMWare software on the box, and everything was running just fine. I am not planning to update or upgrade the VMWware software in the forseeable future.

Recently I got an email from VMWare about support contract renewal, and the cost is quite high. In am inclined not to renew it. I have questions:

1. Am I allowed to continue to use the installed VSphere Client?
2. Will the installed VSphere Client run without any problem? Put it another way, nothing of VSphere Client will be disabled?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: I assume you are using the desktop VSphere client instead of the VSphere web client (either html or flash)?  Edit your question and included this vital information necessary to answer your question

Comment: Worth pointing out the desktop VSphere client hasn’t been updated nor supported by VMWare for years (longer than 3 years) since vCenter 5.5 is older than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I allowed to continue to use the installed VSphere Client?

A VMWare support contract isn’t required to use VMWare products.  You already paid for the rights to the software you have installed.

> Will the installed VSphere Client run without any problem?

I have been using the VSphere desktop client in an isolated environment for the last 5 years.  So it absolutely will have no impact on which features are enabled or disabled since a support contract isn’t required to use any VMWare product.

Comment: @Rmhound, When I bought the Dell box, I bought a VMWare licenses too. Sounds like I will be okay. Thanks!

Comment: One question: my Dell box is connected to the internet, could that be a problem? You mentioned that you system is in an isolated environment.

Comment: @curious1 - No; If an isolated system works without a license server, being connected to the internet won’t be a problem.  Without a support contract VMWare won’t connect to your system to troubleshoot problems but they would do that due to versions your using anyways

Comment: Really appreciate your response. Regards.

Comment: I recall that three years ago, when installing vSphere Client (version 6.0), we entered a license key, does the key contain expiration date (auto-disabling after that date)? What do you mean by "they would do that due to versions your using anyways"?

Comment: I have already answered that question.  I meant to type “wouldn’t”, although 6.0 is supported, figures you were using 5.5

Comment: In any event, your support contract was likely purchased, when you purchased the license to VSphere 6.  It was indeed separate and optional.  **A support contract with VMWare is not required to use any of their software.**

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I indeed purchased a VMWare license when I bought the Dell box. Best.